# How to set up a secure PHP environment on a wide base of PHP configurations

Tags: php, configuration, environment, ini-set

I'm just finishing a CMS that I want to release as open source. The program has some `ini_set()` directives to set a secure environment, like `session.use_only_cookies`, etc. The problem is that some hosts don't allow `ini_set()` and only allow configuration with the `php.ini` file. Is there a way to set up a secure PHP environment on a wide base of PHP configurations? How do other PHP programs face this problem (e.g. Wordpress, Drupal etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking :

- In your software :

  - try to not depend on too many system-wide settings
  - have something that **works with default settings** *(see the php.ini file(s) that are provided with a default PHP installation -- both from php.net, and from the major Linux distributions)*
- Write some short and clear list of requirements
- Code some kind of installation script, that will :

  - check automatically for those requirements,
  - and explain how to set those that are not properly configured

Comment: Do you know by any chance a good resource/article/tutorial which explains how a good setup script should look like and what it should check? Would like to know some good practices, never wrote a setup script before.

Answer (score 0):

You could output a warning if you encounter a setting that you deem unsecure.

Many web apps do it that way, e.g. if the install script isn't deleted, or the administrator has a default password.